# How to uninstall only one specific Go language version (Arch Linux)?

Tags: go, archlinux, installation-package, manjaro

I have 2 Golang versions installed by instructions from:

[official tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/install)

on arch linux manjaro.
How to remove one of them (newer one) that i don't want?

Comment: If you followed the instructions you linked, then you would only ever have one version installed at a time. You'd remove it by `rm -rf /usr/local/go`.

Comment: If you had installed multiple versions using the addendum instructions [here](https://golang.org/doc/install#extra_versions), you'd follow those instructions to remove them (last sentence in that section reads "To uninstall a downloaded version, just remove its GOROOT directory and the goX.Y.Z binary.")

Comment: you might want to check for [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) to manage multiple versions of the go language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your path and remove the GOLANG folder.

```sh
echo $PATH | egrep -i "golang|go|goroot|gobin|gopath"
```

By this way you can understand where the Go is exported in the path.

Than you have to modify your .bashrc (or /etc/profile) in order to remove the Go path/point to the GO version.

In case is no more necessary, delete the old version too.